# NSwag Angular 5 how to get the json response?

Tags: json, typescript, angular5, nswag

I'm accessing an api and I generated using NSwagStudio a type script version of the api calls to use as services. I get the response from the server and seems to work fine, but I don't know how to access the json file with the response. I tried subscribing to the method that I'm calling but I always get null as a response. Any help or guidelines will be appreciated it.

Here is an example of the code generated by NSwagStudio and my implementation to subscribe to the response.

```
apiSubmissionGetResultMessageGet(...) {    
protected processApiSubmissionGetResultMessageGet(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<void> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob = 
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).flatMap(_responseText => {
            return Observable.of<void>(<any>null);
            });
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).flatMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            });
        }
        return Observable.of<void>(<any>null);
    }

}
```

And this is where I'm trying to subscribe:

```
getSubmissionDetails(string): void {
this.client.apiSubmissionGetSubmissionDocumentGet('documentId')
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.submissionList = this.submissionList;
      console.log('data: ', data);
    },
    (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any> error);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is `Observable<void>` which means that it doesnt return anything...

Check that the operation has a response type in the swagger spec and regenerate.